# do something when js element is loaded , is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, timeout, load, setinterval

I have this Jquery function to click on an element when its ready. its an interval doing it , the following function:

```
MonitorAndClick(selector) {
    var ele = $(selector);
    if (ele.length == 0) {
        var intervalid = setInterval(function () {
            var ele = $(selector);

            if (ele.length > 0) {
                ele[0].click();
                clearInterval(intervalid);

                return true;
            }
        }, 500);
    } else {
        ele[0].click();
        return true;
    }
}
```

the problem is **in some cases , its not working**. however this is an interval , and it's checking the element to be ready every 0.5 sec, so how can it be possible ? is there any other way to check the element is ready ?

additional note:

I have an accordion. I have a function to open the accordion->open one of the items->open the tab page in detail section

this is the function :

```
 //--reach to this point, open accordion index 2--------
 ShowAccordion(2);
 //----open the item with specific Id in accordion items------
 setTimeout(function () {
    var selector = "tr[gacategory = '/myprotection/mywills/item_" + parseInt(willId) + "]";
```

MonitorAndClick(selector);
        }, 500);

the point is this element SHOULD be there , sometimes its not loading fast enough , and **I WANT TO HAVE A WAY TO CHECK IF ITS LOADED, THEN CLICK ON THAT.**

**Updated code after comments**

```
var selector = "tr[gacategory = '/myprotection/mywills/item_" + parseInt(willId) + "]";
    $("#selector").ready(function () {
        console.log('**********.... selector is loaded ....*****');
        if (!$("#selector").hasClass('selected')) 
            MonitorAndClick(selector);
    });
```

still not working.

Comment: @CertainPerformance Please check the edited code. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Why do you want to rely on 0.5 seconds delay to make sure your element is present in DOM. You should be invoking this function only after your element is present in the DOM. If there is another condition that drives when this element is added to the DOM, then call this function once that condition is achieved.

Comment: I dont know how to check the element is there, because its is loading , and I just need to wait for it to be loaded. its not something happens only sometimes. it should be loaded finally. how can I check this?

Comment: If it loads during the page on load itself you can use Jquery .ready() 
https://api.jquery.com/ready/

Comment: do u mean I should say 
$('tr[gacategory = '/myprotection/mywills/item_" + parseInt(willId) + "]')..ready( function(){
MonitorAndClick(selector);
} );


I tried that once , but it didnt work

Comment: As per the jQuery API documentation it should work. I just saw your code where you are calling MonitorAndClick. Though you are setting the value for your selector after 0.5 seconds delay, you are calling MonitorAndClick without a delay and probably passing undefined as argument. 

Move that inside the setTimeOut and try

ShowAccordion(2);
 //----open the item with specific Id in accordion items------
 setTimeout(function () {
   var selector = "tr[gacategory = '/myprotection/mywills/item_" + parseInt(willId) + "]";
 MonitorAndClick(selector);
  }, 500);

Answer (score 0):

You may want to try https://api.jquery.com/ready/

It seems like jquery ready function can be applied on individual elements too

Comment: *"can be applied on individual elements too"*. No it can't

Comment: I said it seems .. i was looking at $( "img" ).ready( handler ) , may be i am wrong